# Sell me on unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3

I've been a .Net developer for a long time and am trying to wrap my head around real, practical unit testing.

Most specifically, I'm looking at unit testing ASP.Net MVC 3 projects.

I've read a decent amount about it, and believe I understand it at the academic level (i.e. basically ensures that changes you make aren't going to break other stuff).  However, all of the tests I've seen written in examples are trivially stupid things that would be a pretty obvious catch anyway (does this controller return a view with this name?).

So, maybe I'm missing something, or just haven't seen any really good test examples or something, but it really looks like a crap ton of extra work and complexity with mocking, ioc, etc and I'm just not seeing the counter-balancing gains.

Teach me, please :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unit-testing?sort=votes&pagesize=50

Comment: you are basically saying that you don't see the use with code to test your application, and it assumes the QA testing will find everything. Remember with unit testing, one great advantage is as the app becomes more complex it helps ensure original functionality doesn't break. The tests you stated are trivial, yes, but can greatly help. A better alternative is to test business logic pieces. its hard to demo this - as virtually every app has a different requirement. Test that your validation code does work if a user leaves out for ex. an email address and that you cant save your broken object.

Comment: You may have broken your object validation. Test that a password reset functionality works. Test that the calculation to decrement an order price works when a coupon object is applied. see - its hard to say what is right for you without seeing your app.

Comment: To add to Adam's comments I would say that unless you find an open source project (or a project at your employer) that does unit testing,  it can be hard to see the benefits in practice.  Example code on the internet (and in some books) *is* often 'trivially stupid' due to the nature of example code (short, gets basic idea across, not typically patterned after real-world project).  A unit test that ensures that post conditions remain as originally intended provides for me to unload that information into the code rather than having to remember it all or write some lengthy document that...

Comment: (cont'd) is soon enough out of sync with the software and thrown on a shelf to be later shredded because it's become incorrect due to the evolution of the program.  Having those unit tests in place forces me to deal with answering the question "Something's changed and broken a test.  Why?"  And the answer could be that this new code inadvertently puts things into a bad state.  The answer could also be that the expected behavior has changed and tests need to be re-examined and maybe changed or removed. For non-trivial applications unit testing provides enforcement of expected post-conditions.

Comment: >> it really looks like a crap ton of extra work and complexity ... <<
Because in many cases it is. Unit testing/TDD are being oversold too much, while at the essence it is simply automation of debugging activity, no more no less. If you look at them this way then many Cargo cult myths disappear.
1) "You need 100% coverage" equals "You must step through all your new code in debugger and you must repeat it for all code on every build". 
2) "Tests make design of your system better" equals "sitting in debugger makes your architecture shine". 
etc. 
Automate something that breaks or critical.

Answer (score 0):

Given proper unit testing, it's almost trivial to catch corner-cases that would have otherwise slipped passed you.  Let's say you have a method that returns a list of items and the list of items is retrieved from some table.  What happens if that table isn't populated correctly (e.g. if there's a null value in one of the columns or empty) or if they change the column type to something your ORM tool doesn't map like you thought it would?  Unit tests would help catch these cases before you're in production and someone deletes all of the data in your table.

Answer (score 0):

> basically ensures that changes you make aren't going to break other stuff

This is not unit testing, but [regression testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_testing). [Unit testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) is used to test the smallest pieces of code individually (Usually at the class level). This is not very useful in situations where the projects are small, or there are not may classes.

There are many instances where some form of unit testing (mixed in with other forms usually, I like to use [mock testing](http://agiletesting.blogspot.com/2006/12/mock-testing-examples-and-resources.html) if I have time, for example) is very useful. Say you have a large project with about 20+ classes, and you are getting an error in one of them. You may need to go thorough each class, and make sure that their methods return the correct information. This is unit testing.

In short, unit testing is used when you need to test a specific class, or specific methods, to make sure they are functional. It is a lot easier to find the issue with a program when you are working with the smallest units, and not walking through a whole program to find out what method isn't working right